# How to recursively replace in object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that will recursively replace the string `'{{obj.<key>}}'` in an object `obj` with the value `obj.<key>`. I am assuming the object will always be named `obj`.

For example, if I have the following object:

```js
let obj = { a: '123', b: '456', c: '{{obj.a}}' }
```

It would resolve to:

```
{ a: '123', b: '456', c: '123' }
```

I have tried writing the function `deepReplace` to recursive replace within an object and the function `replace` to perform the regex replacement in the string.

```js
const deepReplace = (globalObj, obj) => {
  switch (typeof(obj)) {
    case 'string':
      obj = replace(globalObj, obj)
      break
    case 'array':
      obj.forEach(item => item = deepReplace(globalObj, item))
      break
    case 'object':
      for (let key in obj) {
        obj[key] = deepReplace(globalObj, obj[key])
      }
      break
    default:
      break
  }
}
```

```js
const _ = require('lodash')
const replace = (globalObj, item) => {
  let newString = item
  let matches = item.match(/[^{\}]+(?=})/g) || []
  for (let match of matches) {
    if (! match === /^obj\./) {
      throw new Error(`Cannot replace ${match}`)
    }
    let target = match.replace(/^obj\./, '')
    let value = _.get(globalObj, target)
    if (value === undefined) {
      throw new Error(`Cannot replace ${match}`)
    }
    newString = newString.replace(`{{${match}}}`, value)
  }
  return newString
}
```

I know `replace` works:

```
> replace(obj, 'value for a: {{obj.a}}, value for b: {{obj.b}}')
'value for a: 123, value for b: 456'
```

However, I can't get `deepReplace` to work. Why does the line `obj = replace(globalObj, obj)` in `deepReplace` not update the object? `replace()` returns correctly, but `obj` does not get updated.

```
> deepReplace(obj, obj)
Error: Cannot replace obj.a
```

Comment: One thing to note is that `typeof []` does not give "array", it gives "object". You can use `Array.isArray(<your array>)` to check if an array is an array

Comment: Maybe try `eval()`? But be aware of the security risk of `eval()` though.

Comment: your arnt returning anything from `deepReplace` so any assignment you are doing is just going to be undefined. Look at the array and object cases. Array also needs to use map since foreach argument is passed by value and wont be replaced in the collection.